# Issue with python subprocess.check_output vs os.system

Tags: python, subprocess

So I'm trying to use the 'newer' subprocess to execute a fortran program in the bash shell... Not sure what I am doing wrong, but if I do

```
result = os.system('./get_cpus -inp ./output_00076 -xc {:.4e} -yc {:.4e} -zc {:.4e} -rad {:.4e}'.format(loc[0],loc[1],loc[2],rad) )
```

I get the fortran program's output (from get_cpus) in result. Thinks seem to work fine... But if I do:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['./get_cpus',
                                 '-inp ./output_00076',
                                 '-xc {:.4e}'.format(loc[0]),
                                 '-yc {:.4e}'.format(loc[1]),
                                 '-zc {:.4e}'.format(loc[2]),
                                 '-rad {:.4e}'.format(rad)])
```

I get an error:

```
./get_cpus -inp ./output_00076 -xc 3.1670e-01 -yc 9.6000e-02 -zc 2.4170e-01 -rad 2.0360e-03
forrtl: severe (59): list-directed I/O syntax error, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Read
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
get_cpus           0000000000409CD8  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
get_cpus           000000000042AF2D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
get_cpus           0000000000429696  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
get_cpus           00000000004065E7  get_cpus_IP_read_         280  get_cpus.f90
get_cpus           00000000004029B1  MAIN__                     46  get_cpus.f90
get_cpus           000000000040297E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.22.so       00007FFFECE456D5  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
get_cpus           00000000004028A9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "findCPUs.py", line 45, in <module>
    '-rad {:.4e}'.format(rad)])
  File "/nasa/pkgsrc/2014Q4/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['./get_cpus', '-inp ./output_00076', '-xc 3.1670e-01', '-yc 9.6000e-02', '-zc 2.4170e-01', '-rad 2.0360e-03']' returned non-zero exit status 59
```

Where the 'CalledProcessError: Command' looks fine to me ...

I've tried this with 'shell=True' and then I get the program to run, but the inputs are all missing because the fortran code returns the 'usage' statement (describing that I need input arguments). ???? e.g. -

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['./get_cpus',
                                 '-inp ./output_00076',
                                 '-xc {:.4e}'.format(loc[0]),
                                 '-yc {:.4e}'.format(loc[1]),
                                 '-zc {:.4e}'.format(loc[2]),
                                  '-rad {:.4e}'.format(rad)],
                                 shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: try providing arguments as one string, rather than a list of strings. I've had scenarios where for some reason that did the trick.

Comment: Note that `shell=True` does not mean `bash` - from the doc:  "*On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `os.system`, you're composing your argument string yourself. It works, but it's ugly, liable to code injection, and not robust to some arguments with spaces if you forget to quote them. So `subprocess` is the right choice.

Now, there are requirements to use `subprocess` with an argument list.

Here your argument splitting is wrong. You're including 2 arguments as one (space separated) for example here:

```
  '-xc {:.4e}'.format(loc[0]),
```

this "argument" is issued to the system like

```
"-xc .4555"
```

(yes, with quotes), and that confuses the argument parsing.

fix: separate the arguments properly:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['./get_cpus',
                                 '-inp','./output_00076',
                                 '-xc','{:.4e}'.format(loc[0]),
                                 '-yc','{:.4e}'.format(loc[1]),
                                 '-zc','{:.4e}'.format(loc[2]),
                                 '-rad','{:.4e}'.format(rad)],
                                 stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
```

you don't need `shell=True` either. It's almost *never* useful except for quick hacks. Often doesn't solve anything, and is a security liability (code injection)

Comment: Thank you... I will try that right now. I would have never have caught that!

Comment: Yep -- that did it. Thank you @Jean-François Fabre